# Positive-definite lattice with O(n,n) Gram matrix generated by minimal vectors

Tags: quadratic-forms, sphere-packing, euclidean-lattices, orthogonal-groups

Consider a positive-definite $2n$-dimensional lattice with minimum norm $\mu$. It is sometimes possible to find a generating set of minimal vectors for the lattice such that the Gram matrix takes the form

$$
K =\left( \array{\mu \mathbb{1} & \sqrt{\mu^2-1} \ R \\ \sqrt{\mu^2-1} \ R^T & \mu \mathbb{1}} \right)
$$
where $\mathbb{1}$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix and $R \in O(n)$. Note that $K \in SO(n,n)$, so the lattice must have determinant 1 (but it need not be integral). Call a lattice with this property "splittable".

I have found Gram matrices of the above form for the optimal lattices in dimensions 2, 4, 8, and 24: $A_2$, $D_4$, $E_8$ and the Leech lattice $\Lambda_{24}$.

The Gram matrix for $A_2$ is easy to find. Just set $\mu = 2/\sqrt{3}$.

For $D_4$, take $\mu = \sqrt{2}$ and
$$
R_{D_4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \array{1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1}\right)
$$

For $E_8$, take $\mu = 2$ and
$$
R_{E_8} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ \left( \array{1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1}\right)
$$

For the Leech, take $\mu = 4$. You can construct the off-diagonal block $\sqrt{15} \ R_{\Lambda_{24}}$ by finding 12 mutually orthogonal vectors of the form $(\pm 1^{11}, \pm 2)$. I won't write out a matrix explicitly.

**Edited to ask:** Are the bases I've written down for these lattices known, or new? For instance, was it known that the Leech can be generated by two sets of 12 mutually orthogonal minimal vectors, where the inner products between the sets give a multiple of an orthogonal matrix?

**Original question:** How do I identify whether a given lattice is splittable? For instance, is the [Quebbemann Q32](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Q32.html) lattice (scaled to have unit determinant) splittable?

**Additional question:** If a lattice with Gram matrix $A$ is splittable, can one algorithmically construct the change of basis $W \in GL(2n,Z)$ that puts $K = W^T A W$ into the specified form?

Based on the results above, one might imagine that there are optimal even-dimensional lattices in dimensions > 24 that are also splittable (perhaps even an infinite family in increasing dimensions).

I'm a total novice, so I'd appreciate any input. Thanks!